# Trouble with QT timers: "function definition is not allowed here"

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make a program that takes images and puts them on your wallpaper using a timer, but I kept getting the error "Timers can only be started with QThread", so I am trying to make this timer with more QThread elements (simpler designs like QThread::msleep haven't worked). Currently, my problem is that my calling slot for when the timer goes off is not working where it currently is, but if I put it in any other location, then the program spits out more errors as it is designed to go in that specific spot. The code itself is mainly a copy/paste of a bunch of other code, and I am new to QT, so I may be going about this completely wrong. If I am, I will gladly accept help so I can understand this better!

```
#include <mainwindow.h>
#include <mythread.h>
QMediaPlayer * BadAppleS = new QMediaPlayer();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication app(argc,argv);

   int fileN = 0;
BadAppleS->setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/SongN/Bad Apple.mp3"));
BadAppleS->play();
mythread t;
t.start();

if (fileN <= 1625) {
    void mythread::doIt(){ //Error here. No more errors elsewhere, though there may be in this function/signal.
     QString fileNQ = QString::number(fileN);
     QString filepath = (("qrc:/BAPics/scene (") + fileNQ + (")"));
     char path[150];
     wchar_t wtext[20];
     strcpy_s(path, filepath.toStdString().c_str());
     mbstowcs(wtext, path, strlen(path)+1);
     LPWSTR pathp = wtext;
     int result;
       result = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, pathp, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
     fileN++;
}
    return app.exec();
  }
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: *"my calling statement for when the timer goes off"* -- your what? Please rephrase or explain this better. Adding to the confusion: what you have marked with a comment is not a statement.

Comment: @JaMiT Sorry, I don't understand some of the QT terms. I should have changed it to the correct terms, but tell me if I didn't.

Comment: The code as posted is creating the `QMediaPlayer` object *before* the `QApplication` object, which is likely to cause problems if the `QMediaPlayer` class wants to use the `QApplication` functionality for anything.  I suggest creating the `QMediaPlayer` object inside `main()` (e.g. maybe just before the `BadAppleS->setMedia()` line) rather than via a global initializer.

Comment: The error message is plain. If you can't understand it, please go to  a library and borrow a good book on C++ syntax. I don't even know how could I help you other than saying that function defnitions are not allowed inside other functions, and  you're trying to define `mythread::doIt()` inside `main()`.

Comment: If you don't know Qt nor basic  C++ syntax, then you're unlikely to be using threads correctly. You really should look for a good books / tutorials on C++ and Qt before you try to use threads in a C++/Qt application.